# Android RSS Example

Tags: java, android

How do you do you fetch a single RSS feed and show it in an ListView?

I realize there's hundreds of ways, but a clean and simple example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Also
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/x-dw-x-androidrss.html

Answer (score 4):

A complete application is here:
http://code.google.com/p/android-rss/

You can download the source code from svn. If you are familiar with Android, it will not be hard for you to solve what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

this is the best site for which you can create sample rss feed application. It consists all things xml parsing,http response,threads,handlers you will get good idea

http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/creating-a-simple-rss-application-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest sample I found was [here](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/RSSReader%253Fstate%253Dclosed).  If you just pull in the classes (RSSItem, RSSParser, and code from the RSSListActivity) in this example you'll be all set in no time.